# link for <table> <tr>

Tags: php, html

Is that possible to give a link to the whole  so that i can create dynamic links to the row shown in front-end from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add an onclick to the TR and then have it point to a function that changes window.location ... pass in a variable of where to point to as a URL.

Comment: In addition: Be sure to use CSS to change the cursor to make it obvious as a click receiver.

Comment: also highlight the entire row in some fashion

Comment: @Rob Olmos & @Galen, both really good points. Thanks for reminding me/him of that. I am so used to having that in my CSS already ;)